# Make array loop dynamic in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have 2 arrays, `$rekeningnum_array` and `$weights`. Both arrays include 10 digits.

```
$rekeningnum_array includes: {3,7,1,6,2,9,3,4,5,2}
$weights always includes: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Each `$rekeningnum_array[i]` object goes `*time`s  a `$weights[i]` array object. So it's `[ i ] x [ i ]`.

After all 10 sums are calculated they're stored in a $answers[i] array and multiplied, then the final answer gets devided by 11. I included a picture to make it easier to understand.

This is my code:

```
$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $ant[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];
    echo $rekeningnum_array[$i] . " x " . $weigts[$i] . " = " . $answer[$i] . "</br>"; 

};



// Multiply all answers and devide them by 11.

$sum = $answer[0] + $answer[1] + $answer[2] + $answer[3] + $answer[4] + $answer[5] + $answer[6] + $answer[7] + $answer[8] + $answer[9];
$antwoord = $sum / 11;
```

My question is, how do I make my code more dynamic?

($gewichten stands for $weights)

[image]

Comment: And where does `$answer` get magically created???

Comment: @RiggsFolly seems like it's the same as `$ant`. And to OP - you have typo in `weigts`

Comment: It gets created in the for loop, the code works perfectly fine!

Comment: If you amend this line to put the calc in an array called `$answer` it will probably magically start working `$answer[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];`

Comment: [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes they're the same in my code. I just translated it for this topic and forgot to change that $ant for $answer.

Comment: And function `count()`

Comment: ___the code works perfectly fine___ This code does not work at all

Comment: We debug what we see. **We cannot debug code we cannot see**

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make a loop also dynamically. use this code

```
<?php
$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$sum=0;
foreach($rekeningnum_array as $key => $value) {
    $ans[$key] = $value * $weights[$key];
     $sum+=$ans[$key];

};

// Multiply all answers and devide them by 11.
echo $antwoord = $sum / 11;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code with my code

```
<?php
    $rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
    $weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    $answer = array(); //New Blank Array is initialized
    for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
       $answer[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];//Here ant variable is changed to answer
       echo $rekeningnum_array[$i] . " x " . $weights[$i] . " = " . $answer[$i] . "</br>"; //Here $weigts spelling mistake

    };



 // Multiply all answers and devide them by 11.

 $sum = $answer[0] + $answer[1] + $answer[2] + $answer[3] + $answer[4] + 
 $answer[5] + $answer[6] + $answer[7] + $answer[8] + $answer[9];
 $antwoord = $sum / 11;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solved Your Issue Please update your code by this code**

```
<?php

$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$ant =0;
for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $ant += $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];
    $now_result = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];
    echo $rekeningnum_array[$i] . " x " . $weights[$i] . " = " . $now_result . "</br>"; 
};
echo $antwoord = $ant / 11;

?>
```

here i define a blank variable $ant before loop
inside loop i add (+=) which add and stores every value on each iteration of loop.
variable $now_result i use only to print each iteration value inside of loop
outside of loop i devide $ant by 11 as you want 
thats simple and short

Comment: You might like to describe the changes you made, so it will be of use to other maybe

Comment: sure here i define a blank variable $ant before loop
inside loop i add (+=) which add and stores every value on each iteration of loop.
variable $now_result i use only to print each iteration value inside of loop
outside of loop i devide $ant by 11 as you want 
thats simple and short

Comment: Not to ME. PUT IT IN YOUR ANSWER

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$weight = 1;
$count = count($rekeningnum_array)-1;
$answer = array();
for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $weight = $weight > 10?1:$weight;
    $answer[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weight ;
    echo $rekeningnum_array[$i] . " x " . $weight . " = " . $answer[$i] . "</br>"; 
 $weight++;
}    
$sum = array_sum($answer);
$antwoord = $sum / 11;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of $weights as they always include the same numbers (1 to 10)? and make this the loop itself that counts from 1 to 10?

Comment: @jasj Sure but what if processed `$i == 11` will  `$weights[11] == 1` or `$weights[11] == 10` ??

Answer (score -1):

you used `ant[$i]` (line no: 4) in as result and spelling of `$weights[$i]` (line no: 5) was not right.

```
$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
    $weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $answer[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];
    echo $rekeningnum_array[$i] . " x " . $weights[$i] . " = " . $answer[$i] . "</br>"; 

};



// Multiply all answers and devide them by 11.

$sum = $answer[0] + $answer[1] + $answer[2] + $answer[3] + $answer[4] + $answer[5] + $answer[6] + $answer[7] + $answer[8] + $answer[9];
$antwoord = $sum / 11;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of $weights as they always include the same numbers (1 to 10)? and make this the loop itself that counts from 1 to 10?

Answer (score -2):

use some thing like that

```
$rekeningnum_array = array(3, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$weights = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$sum=0;
for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $ans[$i] = $rekeningnum_array[$i] * $weights[$i];
     $sum+=$ans[$i];

};

// Multiply all answers and devide them by 11.
$antwoord = $sum / 11;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of $weights as they always include the same numbers (1 to 10)? and make this the loop itself that counts from 1 to 10?